# NameError when appending to a List inside a function (Python)

Tags: python, list, function

Why do I get the error `NameError: name 'l1' is not defined` when I run the code below, will placing the l1 and l2 empty lists outside the functions allow me to append/use the return statements?

```
def function():
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    for x in range(1):
        if 3 > 2:
            l1.append(1)
            l2.append(2)
    return l1, l2

call = function()
print(l1)
print(l2)
```

Comment: `l1` and `l2` are not defined outside of the function (something like `l1=something`). `call` on the other hand, is a tuple containing the two results from your functions. Perhaps you want to change it to `l1, l2 =  function()`, or leaving as is, and instead  `print(call[0])` and `print(call[1])`.

Comment: [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call it like that, `l1` and `l2` are undefined then, so need to do:

```
def function():
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    for x in range(1):
        if 3 > 2:
            l1.append(1)
            l2.append(2)
    return l1, l2

l1,l2 = function()
print(l1)
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[1]
[2]
```